# civix generate:module org.civicrm.angularex error

Tags: drupal, civicrm, civicrm-extension

I have installed a civicrm buildkit with vagrantbox
and vagrant up correctly on windows, ubuntu server run and at d7-master.dev I am listening drupal civicrm all done ok.

as I try to generate module using civix extension builder such as:

in cmd:

```
civix generate:module org.civicrm.angularex
```

I got this error:
  [RuntimeException]
  Failed to determine INI file path.

I tried everything what I knew and what see by google
nothing happens.such as :

```
php --ini
```

works but not resolve this error.

[image]

Comment: might be better to ask on http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to [**set** the appropriate environment variable](https://superuser.com/a/1218436/445903):

1. close your current cmd shell/terminal;
2. press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type `setx CV_CONFIG "%userprofile%\.cv.json"` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>;
3. reopen the shell, goto your project's directory and test with `civix civicrm:ping -vvv`.

I gave further explanations about the reason in [civicrm.stackexchange](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/18988/4741).